# Login with Facebook using $cordovaOauth

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, cordova, ngcordova

I need to clear some doubts here regarding [this ngCordova plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/)

Lets go step by step

1st doubt:

**When registering your application with various service providers such as Facebook or Google, it is very important to use http://localhost/callback as the callback / redirect uri. The Oauth module depends on this in order to complete the browser flow.**

what they mean with the redirect call back ? it is like the route where the app goes after the login ? and where should I put that ?

2nd doubt:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.facebook("CLIENT_ID_HERE", ["email"]).then(function(res) {
            // res
        }, function(err) {
            // err
        });
    }
});
```

what is the `CLIENT_ID` ? is the Facebook `App ID` ? or what ? what should I do withe the array `['email']` ? should I change that to something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use any API, including Facebook, you need to first log into the provider's dashboard and register your application.

In this case, you would probably go to `developers.facebook.com` and register.  When you've done this you'll be given a client id to use within your application.

You're not done yet though.  In the provider dashboard, you need to add `http://localhost/callback` as your `OAuth` redirect `URI`.  You're doing this because `ngCordova` is set up to listen to that `URL`.  When it's found, it knows to close the login flow.

As for scope values, I suggest you read the `Facebook` documentation for a list of values and what they do.

Regards,

Comment: another last question, I am doing my app with Ionic, once I am going to create the app in Facebook, I have around 3 or 4 option, including Web, iOS and Android, should I take Web ?

Comment: Use web because $cordovaOauth initiates a web flow